# Containerized run of OpenAPI generator w/o taking ownership of my folders

Tags: docker, openapi-generator

I'm using the [OpenAPI generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) in a dockerized form:

```bash
docker run --rm \
    -v $PWD:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i /local/petstore.yaml \
    -g go \
    -o /local/out/go
```

while this works, I notice that the files I mapped inside the container are now "owned" by docker and removing them requires a `sudo rm -rf ...`

I've seen various blogs and threads on how to change permissions or `sudo chown` but that doesn't work for me, especially because:

1. I need a Linux + Windows solution
2. I want to be able to clean up artifacts inside the CI/CD pipeline where all this generation happens.

So given I'm only running this command, **is there a way to run it so that the host folder (`$PWD above) being mapped to the container, remains in the ownership of the user that launched the command**?

Comment: Run the container under the same userid as your system user using `--user`?

Comment: Why not report this as a bug to whoever maintains that image?

Comment: @Botje Could you provide an example? That would be `$USER` in Linux and `%USERNAME%` in windows ?

Comment: @NicoHaase Don't think it's an OpenAPI generator bug, I believe containers just behave this way, it's the result of using `-v host_volume:container_volume`. But if there was a way to override this behavior it would be the best solution

Comment: @Botje In Linux passing `--user $(id -u)` worked nicely for me. I don't yet have a windows solution